# Use moderator command for twitch bot

Tags: node.js, bots, twitch

I want to write a bot for the twitch platform. I made a couple of basic commands that will show some links.

But I want the links not just to be displayed, but to be displayed using the `/announce` command, this is a new twitch command that shows the message as an announcement.

But when I display a message with the `/announce` command, I get an error `Unrecognized command: /announce`.

What could be the problem? My bot has moderator rights.

```
const config = require('config')
const client = require('./client.js')
const activeChannel = config.get('channel')
let state = null;

const callCommand = (command, messageInfo) => {
  state = messageInfo;

  switch (command.command) {
    case 'fb':
      client.say(activeChannel, '/announce https://qwe.com')
      break
    case 'twt':
      client.say(activeChannel, '/announce https://zxc.com')
      break
    default:
      break
  }
}

module.exports = {
  call: (command, messageInfo) => {
    callCommand(command, messageInfo)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would suggest that the library you are using (which you didn't say) is interpreting `/announce` as a *server command* so instead of sending

```
PRIVMSG #channel :/announce words
```

it's sending

```
ANNOUNCE #channel :words
```

This might be solvable by using the `.` from of the command so

```
client.say(activeChannel, '.announce https://qwe.com')
```

Should cause the announce to occur.

'Course this all depends on what `client` is and what `say` is/does. Some key information is missing so this is a general suggestion to use the `.` dot form of commands instead of the `/` slash form